# How to install Sphinx 1.3b2 on Mac OS Yosemite for python 3.4

Tags: python, macos, python-sphinx

I have installed Python 3.4 on Mac for developmental purposes. So when I use `which python` on my terminal I get the below
`/usr/bin/python`

And when I do `which python3.4`, I get 
`/usr/local/bin/python3.4`.

Now I have installed Sphinx1.3b2 and on doing `which sphinx-build`, i get 
`/usr/local/bin/sphinx-build`

The problems are

1. I have installed many packages for Python3.4 like elasticsearch, Jinja2 etc. which are not in Python2.7 (my system's python)
2. Make html always uses python 2.7 and I get the following error when i try to make the html for my project;

---

```
sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
    Running Sphinx v1.3b2
    making output directory...
    loading pickled environment... not yet created
    loading intersphinx inventory from http://docs.python.org   /objects.inv...
    building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
    building [html]: targets for 3 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 3 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index
/Users/sourav/Catalobo/catalobo-webapp/SphinxDocs/Code.rst:4: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'catalobo'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3b2-py2.7.egg/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 378, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/Users/sourav/Catalobo/catalobo-webapp/SphinxDocs/catalobo.py", line 4, in <module>
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
ImportError: No module named elasticsearch
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index
generating indices... genindex
writing additional pages... search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en) ... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 1 warning.

Build finished. The HTML pages are in _build/html.
```

As you can see the sphinx-build is not able to load the python 3.4 packages.

Can anyone help me in resolving this?

FYI, I have already tried changing the sphinx-build file with the below;

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4 and /usr/local/bin/python3.4. none works
```

Comment: Apologies for the formatting . I am new to SO and was in a bit of hurry..Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: have you a sym link called python3 pointing to your python3.4  ? Best way of dealing with different python versions on mac is to use mac ports or homebrew or even just create a virtualenv for sphinx

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolved it;

> which sphinx-build
>
> /usr/local/bin/sphinx-build

Now did a vim /usr/local/bin/sphinx-build (or use any text editor) and the below is what I changed.
It was earlier Sphinx==1.3b2 and python2.7

Changed the Sphinx==1.3b2 to 1.2.3 (the installed version of the Sphinx (this was installed usin brew.)
Changed the python to python3.4

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.4
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'Sphinx==1.3b2','console_scripts','sphinx-build'
__requires__ = 'Sphinx==1.2.3'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('Sphinx==1.2.3', 'console_scripts', 'sphinx-build')()
    )
```